# Find Location with Flask WebApp and Google Map

Tags: python, postgresql, google-maps, flask, ubuntu-16.04

I have about 2000 Location Point (Lat, long) in CSV format and I want make a local Flask app (a Python Micro-framework) to send each of this point to google map API and find the address corresponding and save theme.

At first I install PostgreSQL and pgAdmin and then import CSV file to a new database. Secondly I install Virtualenv and also psycopg2 Flask-SQLAlchemy in my env folder

Now I have to make connection between my database and my flask app, then send each of database records (my location points!) to google map and store corresponding address to another filed in my database. but I don't know how I can connect PostgreSQL to Flask app and then how to send points and store address.

- Also I think I have to use geopy in this web app, but how I don't know!

(Python 3.5 - PostgreSQL 9.6 - Linux Ubuntu 16.0.4)

Comment: Why do you need a Flask (Web) app?

Comment: I work on educational data and at the future I want complete this Flask app and publish it to free use in same purpose.

Comment: I think you should start step by step. Do you have a Google maps problem? A Flask problem. A SQLAlchemy problem? How to connect to PostgreSQL problem. Too many things. Not clear what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Um, not enough reputation to comment.

By the way, just use `Psycopg2` module sending query to database, and render the the resultSet.
You have to design what data you want to render to the specific route in Flask.

Google-Maps API provides different types of data return, which kind you needed?

- If you want to show the map in Flask pages, you should work on
  Google-Maps' JavaScript.
- And If you no need to display the data but only store in database, just send the request to the API entry. Use `Request` module and no need `Flask`.

#### geopy.geocoders.GoogleV3

```
>> from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
>> geolocator = GoogleV3()
>> location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
>> print(location.address)
175 5th Ave, New York, NY 10010, USA
>> location = geolocator.reverse("40.7410861, -73.9896297241625")
>> print(location[0])
Flatiron Building, New York, NY 10010, USA
```

Comment: Thanks man, I don't know how I can do this, would you please help me with a tutorial or peace of code or etc.
I am very beginners

Comment: [Google Maps JavaScript Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)

Comment: I checked it, but now it's not suitable for me, I just connect my Flask app to PostgreSQL and then send and receive data with geopy

Comment: ...Just use `geopy.geocoders.GoogleV3` geocoder for google-maps data.